# Data validation in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, validation

I need to validate a column having time ranges like '8:00 am - 9:00 pm' I need to split this column into two and update to my table with the date with current date but the time from the range for example "2011-05-23 08:00:00" And "2011-05-23 21:00:00" for the range record. kindly help. Also I need to process if the data is '8:00 a.m. - 9:00 p.m.', '8:00 a.m - 9:00 p.m' or  '8:00 am - 12:00 noon'. If there is no "-" need to reject the data for the record.

Comment: Why are data coming in such a format in the first place, if you don't mind my prying too much?

Comment: To what degree is the format fixed? I.e. should `'8:00 am - 9:00 pm'` and `'8:00 a.m. - 9:00 p.m.'` be accepted equally? Should `12:00` be always supplied with either `noon` or `midnight`, or are `am` & `pm` allowed too? That is, what deviations should be considered okay and what should be rejected (apart from the absence of `-`)?

Comment: The data currently has only 12:00 noon no midnight, "8:00  - 12:00" must be rejected, '8:00 a.m.  9:00 p.m.' rejected. for now.

Comment: Your question is definitely about processing string data. Different RDBMSes have different sets of tools for that. Therefore you'll have to be more specific about what RDBMS you are using, including its version. (Please add that information to your question.)

Comment: using sqlserver 2008 R2 i am bulk copying from file to the database, but to process to main table i need to do these checks and splits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic solution, which, I think, could well be used as a starting point:

```
DECLARE @Today datetime = CAST(GETDATE() AS date);

WITH datasource (TimeRange) AS (
  SELECT '10 a.m. - 1 p.m.' UNION ALL
  SELECT '8 am - 12 noon' UNION ALL
  SELECT '12 noon - 4 p.m.' UNION ALL
  SELECT '9 - 10 am' UNION ALL
  SELECT '10 am 1 pm'
),
HyphensIncluded AS (
  SELECT *, HyphenPos = CHARINDEX('-', TimeRange)
  FROM datasource
  WHERE CHARINDEX('-', TimeRange) > 0
),
Split AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    StartTimeStr = REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(TimeRange, 0, HyphenPos))),
        '.',
        ''
      ),
      'noon',
      'pm'
    ),
    EndTimeStr = REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        LTRIM(SUBSTRING(TimeRange, HyphenPos + 1, LEN(TimeRange) - HyphenPos)),
        '.',
        ''
      ),
      'noon',
      'pm'
    )
  FROM HyphensIncluded
),
Validated AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Split
  WHERE ISDATE(StartTimeStr) = 1
    AND ISDATE(EndTimeStr) = 1
)
SELECT
  StartTimestamp = @Today + StartTimeStr,
  EndTimestamp   = @Today + EndTimeStr
FROM Validated
```

Output:

```
StartTimestamp          EndTimestamp
----------------------- -----------------------
2011-05-23 10:00:00.000 2011-05-23 13:00:00.000
2011-05-23 08:00:00.000 2011-05-23 12:00:00.000
2011-05-23 12:00:00.000 2011-05-23 16:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be implemented using a trigger. Use 24H time format to avoid dealing with AM/PM.

Comment: how can i do so like i need to split the data from one column to update into columns of the same record. kindly help

Comment: Look Trigger help for your target database. You need to write before/after insert trigger. Logic should be simple, you need to split the column value, and attach date values and save to target columns.

Comment: Rows could be inserted in batches. If you are rolling back the current operation in a trigger, you are rejecting the entire batch of rows being inserted. I think the OP is looking for a way to filter out only the rows with erroneous data.